# how to delete a cookie - C#

Tags: c#, cookies

After cookie deletion user should be redirected to a new page.
On the new page load, system will check for the cookie and do some task if **not** available.

But even after the deletion, the cookie still seems to exist.

Here is the delete code:

```
public static void DeleteCookie()
        {
            HttpCookie currentCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["myCookie"];                
            currentCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            currentCookie.Value = null;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(currentCookie);
        }
```

I am validating the deletion and it still gets the cookie value.

```
///calling this method from another site example2.com, like https://example.com/base/MyTask
public ActionResult MyTask()
{
   DeleteCookie();

   ///redirect to example.com home page
   return Redirect("https://example.com");
}



protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    ///this method is triggered for every request. So, on loading example.com page, this is triggered.

       if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("myCookie") != null)
       {
           //This if condition is always true
       }
}
```

Comment: The cookie in the Request is what it was once the request of the page was made... You cannot validate it server side on the same petition of the page where you set the expiration (because you only tell the client browser to expire/delete the cookie)

Comment: @Cleptus I have edited my question Could you please check.

Comment: My point still stands... You cannot check it server side. Until the client browser recieves the Response and (if it) deletes the cookie you cannot know. You will know in the next Request made.

Comment: With the redirection added to the process, the client browser would/should delete the cookie and then redirect to the URL.

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't be using `HttpContext.Current` - it's not thread-safe. `ActionExecutingContext` contains request information anyway (as does `ControllerBase.Request`)

Comment: @Cleptus. The cookie deletion and the redirection happen at the same time and at the next page load, I want to do some other thing if cookie is deleted. Could you please suggest any other way to achieve that.

Comment: They do not happen "at the next page load". They do happen client side, at the web browser. It recieves the response with the expired cookie and a http redirection code, so the web browser does a new request to the url you said in the .Redirect call. It is in the next page requested where you can check if the cookie exists or not.